# How to sort a list of strings by prefix number then alphabetically

Tags: c#, sorting

My goal is to sort a `List<string>` in messy order to an order like this `["1", "1a", "2", "2a", "2b", "a", "b"]`

My code is a little long, so I've included it at this link https://dotnetfiddle.net/wZ0dTG.

What I'm trying to do is split the strings using `Regex.Split(string, "([0-9]+)")[0]` then based on which strings pass `int.TryParse`, I sort the list numerically or alphabetically.

The regex matches all the integers contained within the string.

Until I apply the regex, it sorts. Although it sorts, it doesn't sort them properly.

When I apply the regex, I get this error:

**ArgumentException: Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results. IComparer: 'System.Comparison`1[Ndot_Partnering_Tool.Data.Models.Project**

Comment: if all you want is like: '["1", "1a", "2", "2a", "2b", "a", "b"]' then you can simply sort the strings, since numbers come before letters in sort order.

Comment: May the list also include "12a" and should it sort before or after "2a"?

Comment: @Klaus "12a" must come after "2a" as well, as if it were 12 coming after 2. Potentially, "100000z" must come after "9000z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to split your strings into an (optional) numeric part and an (optional) rest. This can be done by a Regex:

```
var match = Regex.Match(item, @"(?<number>\d+)?(?<rest>.*)$");
```

The "number" part matches one or more digits, but is optional (question mark), the "rest" part matches the whole rest of the string.

Sorting via Linq:

```
var input = new List<string>{ "12a", "1", "1a", "2", "2a", "2b", "a", "b", "12a" };
var sorted = input.OrderBy(item =>
{
    var match = Regex.Match(item, @"(?<number>\d+)?(?<rest>.*)$");
    return Tuple.Create(match.Groups["number"].Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value) : -1, match.Groups["rest"].Value);
}).ToList();
```

(I deliberately decided to put the items without a leading number before the rest; this was not specified in the question).

Output: a, b, 1, 1a, 2, 2a, 2b, 12a

Answer (score 1):

For this particular task the OrderBy method is perfect for you. I would use that instead of Regex.
OrderBy uses lambda expressions as a key to sort.
Since letters are after numbers in the alphabet this method is using, you can actually just sort by default.

You can do:

```
List<string> List = new List<string>() {"a", "2b", "1a", "1", "2", "2a", "b", "1b" };
List<string> OrderedList = List.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

The OrderBy method returns IEnumerable so you have to convert it back to List.

Output:

The original list: a 2b 1a 1 2 2a b 1b

The ordered list: 1 1a 1b 2 2a 2b a b

Comment: Technically, this doesn't sort 12a after 2a, but it does the job well enough. I think what I was originally asking was impossible because it could potentially sort two equivalent strings differently. Plus, I just love this OrderBy linq.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. SplitRegex() failes on argument "a" because it does not match regex (RegEx.Split returns array with one element). You can use this code:

   return Regex.Split(x, "([0-9]+)").ElementAtOrDefault(1) ?? string.Empty;
2. When neither x nor y can be converted to integer, you call CompareString() for x and y, but x and y are not whole strings, they are only numerical parts (and because of that empty). You need to pass list items as is to comparer and extract numbers there:

   ```
    bool leftcanconvertflag = Int32.TryParse(SplitRegex(x), out leftconvertresult);
    bool rightcanconvertflag = Int32.TryParse(SplitRegex(y), out rightconvertresult);
    if (leftcanconvertflag && !rightcanconvertflag)
    {
        compareresult = -1;
    }

    if (!leftcanconvertflag && rightcanconvertflag)
    {
        compareresult = 1;
    }

    if (leftcanconvertflag && rightcanconvertflag)
    {
        compareresult = leftconvertresult.CompareTo(rightconvertresult);
    }

    if (!leftcanconvertflag && !rightcanconvertflag)
    {
        compareresult = CompareString(x, y);
    }
   ```

and sort list like this:

```
list.Sort(CompareContractNumbers);
```